# remove duplicated line between label and node

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I would like to remove the duplicate line between node and node label as below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,node distance=0 and 0]

  \tikzset{
    box/.style={draw,minimum width=5em,text width=5em,minimum height=1.6em,inner sep=1pt},
  }
  \def\nodes{
AAA,
BBBB,
CCCCC,
DDDDDD
}
\begin{scope}[start chain=C1 going below]
\foreach \f/\t/\n/\s [count=\i] in \nodes {
  \node[box,on chain=C1] {\small \n};
  }
\end{scope}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node[fit=(C1-1)(C1-4),draw,inner sep=2pt,label={[anchor=south west,draw]north west:package}]{};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The line under `package` is drawed two times. it feels like thicker.

Output:

[image]

Comment: The line is not just drawn twice. There are two separate lines. The anchors lies outside the node border - not on the border.

Answer (score 1):

You can shift the label vertically by the line width by adding `yshift=-\pgflinewidth`. You can also change the `node distance` in the chain to `-\pgflinewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,node distance=0 and 0]

  \tikzset{
    box/.style={draw,minimum width=5em,text width=5em,minimum height=1.6em,inner sep=1pt},
  }
  \def\nodes{
AAA,
BBBB,
CCCCC,
DDDDDD
}
\begin{scope}[start chain=C1 going below, node distance=-\pgflinewidth]
\foreach \f/\t/\n/\s [count=\i] in \nodes {
  \node[box,on chain=C1] {\small \n};
  }
\end{scope}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node[fit=(C1-1)(C1-4),draw,inner sep=2pt,label={[anchor=south west,draw,yshift=-\pgflinewidth]north west:package}]{};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```